# Bamboo is showing "Testless build" if any of my tests failed

Tags: parsing, reporting, bamboo

I am trying to run C# automation Test from bamboo using MS build.

I have also used Parser to show proper number of pass/failed tests.

It seems, when my all tests passes, it shows the total number of tests, for example: 30 tests passed, however when one of the tests failed, it shows "**Testless build**"

Have anyone else come across this issue? I am using parser, but not sure where am I making mistake

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show your effort

Comment: Is it when a test fails or when the build fails you get this?  Also can you show what arguments you are using in the parser task?